# Action script 3 so slow mouse over reaction

Tags: actionscript-3, delay, mouseover, movieclip, event-listener

I have a mouse over event listener on some of my movieclips. When the mouse hover over them I want them to scale. Which works perfectly except for the delay of 2 or 3 seconds between the mouse is over and something actually happens on screen. Why?
Ty

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

public class Airport extends MovieClip
{
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public static var collectedMovieClipsArray:Array = new Array();
            public static var ROUTING:boolean = true;


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function Airport(navninput, bynavninput)
    {
        collectedMovieClipsArray.push(this)

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverHandler);
    }



    private function hoverHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (ROUTING == true)
        {
            this.alpha = 60;
            this.width = 2*this.width;
            this.height = 2*this.height;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, awayHandler);
        }
    }

    private function awayHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
            this.width = 13;
            this.height = 13;
    }




}
}
```

Comment: Do your code is playing animations using `ENTER_FRAME` event?

Comment: No, my code is not based on frames

Answer (score 0):

Low fps and/or the swf is overloaded with math or graphics. How much are you scaling and from what size? are you playing a transition for the scaling? more details always help.

Comment: I'm just scaling with times 2... However I'm trying to develop my code from being based on timeline to classes and packages, and the movieclips are dynamically added as children to another movieclip. They have to be though. I'm encountering so many difficulties and bugs atm.

Comment: edit your question with the over event handler function.

Comment: what is your frame rate?

Comment: crank it up to 30. Somewhat of a standard.